A problem about affine transformation
The formula of affine transformation on a given plane is
$$
x'=2x+4y-1 \\ y'= 3x+3y-3
$$
We can find the formula for the invariant lines
$$x-y-1 = 0 \\ 3x+4y-3 = 0 $$
But if we take these two invariant lines as the new coordinate axes, how can I find the formula of the affine transformation in this coordinate system? I am confused and any help will be appreciated.
